# Batch find text with quotation marks

Tags: batch-file, find

1.

i use code to find test in file

```
>nul find "uset g_save_format "2"" log.txt && (
  echo "uset g_save_format "2"" was found.
) || (
  echo "uset g_save_format "2"" was NOT found.
)
```

how to find the text with "" for example:

```
uset g_save_format "2"
```

2.

```
cd c:\
cd c:\users\%username%\Documents\
>nul find "uset g_save_format ""0""" config.cfg && (
  goto savepyt
) || (
  goto scsc
)
```

how to write my code with findstr?

I have a problem to save the path with findstr

```
findstr  /c:\users\%username%\Documents\ "uset g_save_format \"2\""
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>nul find "uset g_save_format ""2""" log.txt && (
  echo "uset g_save_format "2"" was found.
) || (
  echo "uset g_save_format "2"" was NOT found.
)
```

In FIND (though it is not documented by MS) command quotes are escaped with quotes.
You can try also with FINDSTR -

```
findstr  /c:"uset g_save_format \"2\""
```

Comment: 1) It is [documented](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490906.aspx): *"If the string you want to search for contains quotation marks, you must use two quotation marks for each quotation mark contained within the string"* 2) the `findstr` sample is missing a `/c:`

Comment: @MCND - it's missing in the `FIND /?`

Comment: Yes, the text in the command's help is limited, but the linked technet reference includes it. I don't have it at hand now, but I will see if the `.hlp` and `.chm` files in the system help also include it.

Comment: Done. I've checked the help files in XP (ntcmds.chm) and NT 4 (ntcmds.hlp) and in both cases it is documented. Just for curiosity I've checked the source code of MS-DOS 2.0, and the comments in `FIND.ASM` include: *"String arguments HAVE to be enclosed in double quotes. (Two double quotes if a doble quote is to be included)"*

Answer (score 0):

it is documented actually for the find command, according to the following page:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/find

If the string you want to search for contains quotation marks, you must use double quotation marks for each quotation mark contained within the string (for example, """This string contains quotation marks""").